# How to align image, text and button on one line with out tables

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a movie poster image, description text & add to cart button on the same line. The text needs to be centered aligned and not wrap around button or image. It should look like this.

[image]

However, with my current code, it looks like this. Movie description text is not center-aligned and it wraps around the button.
[image]

This is my code. How can I modify it to fix it to look like the first image?

```
    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="pull-left"><img src="https://{{movie.image}}" alt="[Image Missing]" width="70px" /></div>
        <br><span>{{movie.description}}</span>
        <span>
            <button class="float-right btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addToCart(movie)">
                Add to Cart
            </button></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve your problem.

You can use `flex`

```css
 .container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
     }
     
.container .item:nth-child(2){ /*Only second item padding and center text*/
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x100">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sagittis sagittis enim. Nulla viverra aliquam.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <button> Add to cart </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Or you can try with the new `CSS-Grid`, but it's not supported at all on some browsers yet

```css
.container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr; /*Here you set how many columns will be and how much of the space they will take, for example there are 3 values, meaning 3 columns, the first and the last one will take 1 space of the row, and the second one will take 4 spaces*/
      align-items: center;
      grid-gap: 1em; /*The gap between items*/
    }
    
    .container .item:nth-child(2) {
       text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
              <div class="item">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x100">
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sagittis sagittis enim. Nulla viverra aliquam.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                  <button> Add to cart </button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Cool. The 2nd example is closest to what I want. The button isn't all the way flushed to the right when I maximize but it is aligned with other buttons at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `flex` instead, this is example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center
}
p {
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit amet est vel erat rutrum tempus. Etiam auctor dapibus magna, ut auctor metus pretium sed.
  </p>
  <button>
    Add
  </button>
</div>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks! Almost there. How can I make the button flush align to the right? With this fix, it's not flush right when I maximize the window.

Comment: @myfunnyfella I am wondering your button is wrapped by an span, right? In this case you just need add one line of CSS to your span: `text-align: right;`